# End of input at character 0 of excrption in android 10

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using android volley and getting the following exception but only in android 10 (till android 9 it's working fine):

```
com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of End_of_input_at_character_0_of
```

Comment: share code with details

Comment: Why do you think this error is only related to Android 10? Don't you think it's cause of a different reason?

Comment: I tested with 6 different android devices ( 3 with Android 10 and 3 with below 10 ) and I faced this issue with only android 10, I Am using standard android network requests using Volley

Comment: I found Solution By Just adding   android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" tools:targetApi="n"  in Application tag in  manifest and  <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />